# How can I insure jQuery submits the correct JSON keys in the headers using POST?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post

I have this snippet,

```
 pKey = $(this).attr("data-pk");
 var columnName = $(this).attr("name");
 var changedData = $(this).val();
 var data = {
        id : pKey,
        columnName : changedData
    };

    $.post('/HelloWorld/Edit/', data, function () {
        $("#status").html("<strong>" + pKey + ", " + myCurrentData + ": POST SUCCESS?:</strong>");
    })
```

When I step through the code in Chrome, data has the correct columnName.  It would be this:

```
var data = {
    id: pKey,
    lastName : changedData
};
```

That's what Chrome shows, but when I see the headers it shows this:

```
columnName : mydatathatgotchanged
```

In other words, it keeps the name of the column literally "columnName" and then the data.  It is changing somehow.  The changedData value is correct.

Comment: You can't use variables as Javascript object names, try to key into the object using [] notation instead and use your variable name.  `data[columnName] = changedData`

Comment: I think it is working now.  I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way:

```
...
var data = {id: pKey};
data[columnName] = changedData;
...
```